# Selecting Objects from an ArrayList using Keyboard Input

Tags: java, arrays, input, arraylist, keyboard

thanks for coming by. I have been working on a game inventory system, its been working awesome when I pick items from the world and then they get added into the list and displayed inside an inventory box when I hit "I", but now I want to be able to interact with them using the arrow keys and the ENTER key, every item has a method called "use" in which it executes an action, (Ex: HP potion, increases player health) now I want to be able to select items from the list and when I hit enter that the selected item's method "use" is actually used, I've got the input handling covered, I only wish to know how to access the objects inside the arraylist depending on the selected choice.

So far I got:

```
private int currentChoice=0;//the value is the index position within the
                            //array, so 0 would mean I selected an object 
                            //at index 0.

private ArrayList<Item> playerItems;//This is the array in which I store
                                    //the player's items.

private boolean inventoryDisplayed;//This is used when I click "I" then the 
                                   //the arrow keys stop moving the player
                                   //and should now be used to interact with
                                   //the items inside the inventory.
```

If you guys could help me that would brighten my week, seriously, this project is very important to me, any help is very appreciated, thanks for taking your time to help a fellow member from stackOverflow, may good fortune shine on your life, have a big choco cookie just for reading up 'till here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can get the element at a specific position in a list by using

```
list.get(index);
```

or in your case

```
 playerItems.get(currentChoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, define playerItems as `private List<Item> playerItems;` and then instantiate it as `playerItems = new ArrayList<Item>();`. This is one of the core principles of well designed code, particularly if you need to change playerItems to a `LinkedList` later on.

You'll need to add a `KeyListener` or `KeyAdapter` to the appropriate component when the 'i' character is typed. Then, implement the keyTyped (or maybe the keyPressed) method as follows:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch(e.getKeyChar())
    {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            if(--currentChoice < 0)
                currentChoice = playerItems.size() - 1;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            if(++currentChoice >= playerItems.size())
                currentChoice = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve the appropriate item with: `playerItems.get(currentChoice);`

Comment: I do instantiate playerItems = new ArrayList<Item>(); within the init method of the game state, just putting that up in there so you have stuff to work with when brainstorming.